# Spring boot (v2.6.7) security with JWT, web.ignoring() is working but not antMatchers permitAll()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I migrated Spring boot from 2.1.5 to 2.6.7. Now the security configuration is throwing a warning about antMatchers in web.ignoring in the WebSecurity configuration lines, although it works correctly. Upon moving the web.ignoring to antMatchers permitAll() in httpConfiguration, the warning goes away but the urls are no longer permitted.

I am also using JWT and it looks like the JWT filters are kicking in and not honoring the httpConfiguration. I am really confused as to how to configure this. I am including the before and after here.

WORKS WITH WARNING:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void init(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.init(web);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("**********************SECURITY INITALIZE NORMAL#######################################");
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**");
    }
}
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void init(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.init(web);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("**********************SECURITY INITALIZE NORMAL#######################################");
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()         // ADDED LINE 
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**");
    }
}
```

Looks like somehow the configuration breaks when using http security versus web security. I have tried many of the suggestions but nothing seems to work.

Can someone familiar with Spring Boot Security in 2.6.7 with JWT filters please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The first override is useless since you just pass it onto the super function so you can remove that. Second ow all, there is no need to have a custom jwt filters as there is already a built in jwtfilter in spring security? Why not just read the JWT section in the spring security docs? Last read up the difference between HttpSecurity and Websecurity and you will then understand your problem

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare. I agree with your suggestion. I have the read docs. I am here because I don't understand the docs and seeking help from experts who actually have this working in Spring Boot 2.6.7.

Comment: Note that I have commented out the web.ignoring line in the 'does not work' code. Spring Boot 2.6.7 does not like web.ignoring and recommending to use http permitAll(). But it is not clear how to transition to that when using JWT filters. This is the specific part I need clarification from anyone who has working code in Spring Boot 2.6.7.

Comment: Its because using custom jwtfilters is bad practice. Custom security is bad. Please read the chapter on resourceservers/jwts in the documentation on how to actually implement jwts in spring security. Its had full jwt support since 2018 because the way you are doing it is not right

Comment: @Venky The solution is to use two different security chains. One only for the ignoring part and one for the other part. In the ignoring part you could remove the custom filter part. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10938

Comment: "I am also using JWT and it looks like the JWT filters are kicking in and not honoring the httpConfiguration." This is probably because the custom JWT filters are not correctly ignoring requests that do not provide an `Authorization` header. The `permitAll()` authorization rule only applies to requests that have passed all the way through the security filter chain. Does that help? I would definitely recommend replacing them with `.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)`. See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html).